# Can not login after moving to cloudflare and adding rules

Tags: login, dashboard, cache, cdn, cloudflare

I've setup my website with [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/). In the settings, I've added some rules to make it faster.

Since then, when I try to login the *Dashboard*. I get the following message:

> **ERROR**: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.

However, my cookies are enabled. I suspect that it is because of my rules that I've set up:

`mysite.com/`

- **Custom caching**: everything
- **Edge cache expire TTL**: 1 week
- **Browser cache expire TTL**: 8 days

The rest was set up by default:

`mysite.com/*.php` and `mysite.com/wp-admin`

- **Custom caching**: Bypasscache
- **Browser cache expire TTL**: 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen on other browsers?

It does appear that you are using aggressive caching - add a rule to prevent caching to wp-admin as it does not function well when it is cached.

See if these work:

```
*.yourdomain.com/wp-admin/*
*.yourdomain.com/wp-login.php*
```

Answer (score 0):

Your wildcard matching rule for bypassing the cache is not set up properly.

Try **mysite.com/wp*** (which will match all the admin pages plus the login page, and works well for me)